# PHP password_verify

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on making a login section for my project website using PHP, but for some reason, `verify_password` won't return true, even when I am giving the correct password. No idea what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the code that I use to add the user to the MySQL table:

```
$password= $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash('$password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// I know this isn't inject proof
$res = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO login (SSN, UserName, passhash) VALUES (:SSN, :UserName, :passhash)');
$res->bindValue(':SSN', $_POST['UserName']);
$res->bindValue(':UserName', $_POST['UserName']);
$res->bindValue(':passhash', $hash);
$res->execute();
```

It stores the hash in a varchar(60)
Here is the code that takes the password, and verifies it against the hash:

```
   $userName = $_POST['UserName'];
$password= $_POST['password'];

// I doubt this is inject proof
$res = $conn->prepare("select passhash from login where UserName='$userName'");
//$res->bindValue(':SSN', $_POST['UserName']);
//$res->bindValue(':UserName', $_POST['UserName']);
//$res->bindValue(':hash', $hash);
$res->execute();
$result = $res->fetch();

if(!empty($result) && password_verify($password, $result['passhash']))
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Note that the PHP manual for password_hash() recommends that you use a field larger than 60 characters in order to accommodate longer hashes produced by future algorithms. They suggest 255 characters. See the first example on [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: This question can be closed as typo/unreproducible, given the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes prevent variable interpolation, so this encodes the literal string `$password` as the password:

```
$hash = password_hash('$password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Just use the variable directly:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: >.> That fixed it. Thanks!